# Why do I have to explicitely specify primary key while this is specified in my AutoField model?

Tags: oracle, django-models

I have a very basic Oracle table named TestJbl with two fields:

ID (number, not NULLABLE) which is the primary key. 
DATAS (varchar2, NULLABLE).

I want to be able to insert DATAS without having to specify the ID column.

My problem: eventhough ID is explicitely set to AutoField (primary_key=True) in my model as you can see bellow:

```
class TestJbl(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    datas = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'test_jbl'
```

when I try:

```
>>> a = TestJbl(datas='A')
>>> a.save()
```

I got an Oracle Error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("RTDIAG"."TEST_JBL"."ID")
```

Why is this ? AutoField is it not supposed to auto-indent my primary key ?

NB: I'm Using Python 2.6.6 and Django 1.5.5

Comment: Apparently Django will create the necessary Oracle sequence and trigger if it's also creating the table, but if you're using an existing table, you'll have to do it manually. https://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/193/

Comment: If you're on Oracle 12c, I think Django 2 supports IDENTITY columns, which are easier.